# I have trouble in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I have exam, and I am studying Linked List, but I do not understand why in add method  `list` is not used and `current` is used instead of it. I tried it it gives logic error. `Current` is copy of `list` so both of them should give same answer.

```
public class MagazineList
{
    private MagazineNode list;

    public MagazineList() {
        list = null;
    }


    public void add(Magazine mag) {
        MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode(mag);
        MagazineNode current;

        if(list == null) {
            list = node;
        } else {
            current = list;
            while(current.next != null)
                current = current.next;
            current.next = node;
        }
    }


    public String toString() {
        String result = " ";

        MagazineNode current = list;
        while (current != null) {
            result += current.magazine + "\n";
            current = current.next;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private class MagazineNode
    {
        public Magazine magazine;
        public MagazineNode next;


        public MagazineNode(Magazine mag) {
            magazine = mag;
            next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're seeing? This looks fine to me. (And use the `{}` button to indent your code.)

Comment: Note that the default value of object fields is null, so your constructor is redundant (but not harmful).

Comment: @chrylis answer should be  Time
WoodworkingT
Communucations
House
GQ
But when i change current and use list insdead of it , it gives  Time

GQ

Answer (score 2):

`list` is the head of the list. You don't want to change that unless you're adding something at the head and you need to update it.

That's why you set the node `current` to `list` (head of LinkedList) and then only change the current node (`current = current.next`).

If you changed `list` (`list = list.next`), you would change the head of the linked list and wouldn't be able to go back.

In the add method specifically, after iterating through the nodes `list` would actually point to the tail of the list and you wouldn't be able to access any other elements (unless it was doubly linked).